# Erase method for raphael object

Tags: algorithm, raphael

is there a way to implement a erase method for raphael objects. in this erase method I want to remove specific parts of a particular raphael object. It means that the erase method should work like a real eraser. In the raphael documentation there is a method call **Paper.clear()**. But we only can delete entire paper. 
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to be to use the remove() method.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.remove

```
element.remove();
```

Comment: I'm sorry if you couldn't understand the question clearly. I edit the question. from remove method, element is removed completely. but I want remove specific parts of the element. like a eraser in ms paint. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use remove() on the specific part you want. I suspect you mean something else entirely and mean hide bits of a subpath or something, but thats not what the question is asking. I think you probably want to ask a new question with the example elements that you want to 'erase' and what specific 'effect' you actually want on a jsfiddle. Also have a read of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/2xigYMELBY0 in case that matches

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually create a function that draws shapes with the same color than your paper background-color, on click. Something like this code (jsfiddle at the end of the post). It would cover your content and not erase it, but it would look like it.

```
            var timeoutId = 0;
            var cursorX;
            var cursorY;
            var mouseStillDown = false;

            paper = Raphael("paper1","100%","100%");

            paper.rect(10,10,100,100).attr({
                fill : "black"
            });

            $("#paper1").mousemove(function(event){
                cursorY=event.pageY;
                cursorX=event.pageX;
            });

            function erase() {
                if (!mouseStillDown) { return; }                                
                paper.rect(cursorX-25,cursorY-25,50,50).attr({
                   fill :"white",
                   stroke : "white"
                });

                if (mouseStillDown) { setInterval("erase", 100); }
            }

            $("#paper1").mousedown(function(event) {
                mouseStillDown = true;
                erase(event.pageX,event.pageY);
            });

            $("#paper1").mouseup(function(event) {
                mouseStillDown = false;
            });
```

Here, each time you click, it creates a white rectangle at your cursor position.

Here's a fiddle of the code : http://jsfiddle.net/c6Xs6/

With a few modifications you could create a menu allowing the user to choose the size and shape of the form you use to "erase".
Something more or less like this :  http://jsfiddle.net/8ABe9/

You could also use a div following your cursor to show exactly where the "eraser" would be drawn.

Hope that helped you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but here you apply white color for erase method. But what happen when the particular shape or part of a shape lies on a green color and when we use this erase method, it fills the white color on top of it ???

Comment: Well i guess you could do like in the second jsfiddle and have some way to change the color of the shape you're drawing, according to the background color. Why not something like the color-picker in paint?